# If quantity is 6 or multiple of 6 so 1% discount

Tags: php, ajax

HI Friends> I wants if quantity is 6 or 12 or 18 or 24 so the price of the product will be 10% off for each product.

For example if quantity is 8 so 6 quantity price will be 10% off and remaining 2 quantity will be no discount. 
Like total 8 quantity=8
6 quantity* 10% product price
2 quantity * full product price
TOtal price will be for 8 quantity=(6 qty price with 10% off)+(2 qty with full price.)

I want this in PHP. Please help me

Comment: This will tell you if there is a remainder after dividing by 6.  No remainder, it's a multiple.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-div-r.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is magic.

```
$magicPriceFunction = function ($pricePerItem, $itemCount) {
    $magicNumber = 6;
    $discount    = 0.1;

    $unhappyItemCount = $itemCount % $magicNumber;

    $total  = 0;
    $total += $pricePerItem * $unhappyItemCount;
    $total += ($itemCount - $unhappyItemCount) * (1 - $discount) * $pricePerItem;

    return $total;
};

var_dump($magicPriceFunction(100, 6));
```

Comment: Thanks Pavlunya for replying me. Help full for me. I appreciate your efforts. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is one way you could do it

```
$quantity = 8;
$remainder = $quantity % 6 ? $quantity % 6 : 0;
$discountItems = $quantity - $remainder;    
echo "10% off " . $discountItems . " items and full price on " . $remainder;
// 10% off 6 items and full price on 2
```